# Update column that has an increment

Tags: mysql

I have a column called `order` the column allows me to go through each one in a for loop, the table has some entries for each user. the problem is that every time I need to update it because I erase an entry or because I add another one I have to erase them and re-insert them to be able to have the `order` column numbered from 1 to the number of records for that user, this applies to entries for each user. I want to mention that I have a column `id` that is auto-increment. I want to know what can I do to update the column and have the `order` column numbers re-ordered that way I don't have to erase them all?

Comment: Is it necessary that you have a order column to track the order? Can you just order the data by another column?

Comment: I do need that column as my program needt it to go through each one in a loop

Comment: You can always loop through all rows returned from a MySQL query. You'd only need a column to organize rows, not to loop through them. Can you give an example schema for your table and show how you're trying to loop through the result?